# JSON criado com PHP passar para o JAVASCRIPT

Tags: php, javascript, json

PHP le um arquivo CSV e gera um JSON

```
require __DIR__ . '\autoload.php';
use League\Csv\Reader;
$arq = __DIR__ . '\arquivos\201111019050.csv';

$reader = Reader::createFromPath($arq, 'r');
$records = $reader->getRecords();
$tmp = new SplTempFileObject();
foreach ($records as $offset => $record) {
    $tmp->fputcsv($record);
}

$reader = Reader::createFromFileObject($tmp);
$reader->setDelimiter(';');
$reader->setHeaderOffset(0);
$reader = json_encode($reader);
?>
```

Descarregar o JSON que esta no PHP para o JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
    // ACHO QUE MEU ERRO ESTA AQUI 
    var arrayOfObjects = "<?="$reader"?>";
    // -----------------------------------
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfObjects.length; i++) {
        var object = arrayOfObjects[i];
        for (var property in object) {
            alert('item ' + i + ': ' + property + '=' + object[property]);
        }

    }
</script>
```

Arquivo CVS - 201111019050.csv

```
[
{"sistema":"xxxx","dt_ini":"01:16","dt_fim":"03:20","dt_esti":"03:13","job":"xxxxx"},
{"sistema":"aaaaa","dt_ini":"01:42","dt_fim":"03:46","dt_esti":"03:47","job":"aaaaa"},
{"sistema":"bbbbb","dt_ini":"01:17","dt_fim":"03:21","dt_esti":"03:25","job":"bbbbb"},
{"sistema":"ccccc","dt_ini":"02:28","dt_fim":"04:32","dt_esti":"04:42","job":"ccccc"},
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Tens aspas a mais e devias usar `;` no PHP. Depois tens de fazer parse dessa string para um JSON. Podes fazer isso em JavaScript com `JSON.parse`

Muda:

```
var arrayOfObjects = "<?="$reader"?>";
```

para

```
var json = "<?=$reader;?>";
var arrayOfObjects = JSON.parse(json);
```

Comment: Não funcionou ainda.<br> quando coloco as dados do JSON direto na variável do JavaScript, funciona, mais quando pego no variável do php não rola.

Comment: @LeonelEloy podes colocar na pergunta o HTML que é produzido nessa linha?

Comment: Sergio HTML esta, como uma resposta !!!!!